# What's the difference between "would" and "will" in the following context?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> How would he do that?

And

> How will he do that?

Comment: What research have you done on this topic? There is a wealth of information available on the Internet about the difference between "would" and "will". Have you looked?

Answer (score 1):

> How will he do X?"

- He wants to do X and is asking how, or
- He wants to do X and we are trying to guess how it will happen.

> How would he do X?

- Same as above, but there's an *if Y* implied, or
- Same as above, but in the past; i.e. he wanted to do X and was asking how, or he wanted to do X and we were trying to guess how it would happen.